# How to fill out DTO in C#

Tags: c#, database, foreach, dto

I'm have trouble reading my list of DTOs.

I wish to receive a list of DTOs from a database so I can put them in a table on the WPF part, but when I run the program there is no data in the list, and there are no errors. I do not understand why, is there something wrong with my code?

```
   public IList<ProductDTO> GetProducts()
{
       IList<ProductDTO>listofproducts = new List<ProductDTO>();
       ProductDTO productDto = new ProductDTO();


    using (var db = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
        var query = from p in db.Products

                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.ProductName,     
                    };

        foreach (var product in query)
        {
            productDto.Name = product.Name;
            listofproducts.Add(productDto);
        }

        return listofproducts;
    }     
}
```

Updated VERSION:

I'm getting a error called entityexception was unhandled by user code at the end of the code (tolist)

```
 public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> GetProducts()
        {
            using (var db = new NORTHWNDEntities())
            {
                return db.Products.Select(m => new ProductDTO { Name = m.ProductName }).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are adding the same reference to the list multiple times

Comment: Does query actually return anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the same reference to the list.  You can fix it like this:

```
public IList<ProductDTO> GetProducts()
{
    IList<ProductDTO>listofproducts = new List<ProductDTO>();
    using (var db = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
        var query = from p in db.Products
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.ProductName,     
                    };
        foreach (var product in query)
        {
            listofproducts.Add(new ProductDTO {Name = product.Name});
        }
        return listofproducts;
    }     
}
```

Or

```
    public IList<ProductDTO> GetProducts()
    {
        using (var db = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {
            return db.Products.Select(m=>new ProductDTO{Name = m.ProductName}).ToList();
        }     
    }
```

Comment: @Zaz You can totally get rid of the foreach if you select into the ProductDTO right out of the select statement. Then, making it even better, you return a IQUeryable of ProductDTO and the user can add filters as he sees fit.